# wrapper data not showing in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, table

[image][image][image]i am triing to display wrapper data into  table in lightning, but its  displaying null data [image]

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question to include relevant information, like the wrapper, the method used to retrieve the data, and the component's markup and logic. This will allow us to better serve you. Please read **[ask]** for more information.

Comment: i have written wrapper class to calculate totals per month , but i am able to get data in the background its not showing in UI

Comment: Again, please **[edit]** your question with more information. We want to help you! A simple screenshot of what's going on isn't enough. Code speaks a lot more than pictures here. More details is better help for you.

Comment: There is a known issue around wrapper class. Like @sfdcfox said please post your code here so the community members can help you efficiently. https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001CBeQAM&title=lightning-components-can-t-use-inner-classes-as-attribute-type-when-the-org-has-setup-a-namespace .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of e.g.:

```
value="{!v.con.janTotal}"
```

for your case it is just e.g.:

```
value="{!con.janTotal}"
```

Inconsistently, the `v.` prefix is required to access `aura:attribute` values but not to access the `var` of an `aura:iteration`.

Answer (score 1):

Although you didn't post any code, there's a good chance you need to add `@AuraEnabled` to the variables in your wrapper in your controller.

Example:

```
public class Controller {

    public class Wrapper {
       @AuraEnabled
       public Decimal janTotal;
    }

}
```

Comment: i have kept @AuraEnabled attribute already

Comment: Can you post your javascript controller code as well?

Comment: I have attached javascript screen shot